# Oracle SQL Tuning Advisor Accepting Recommendation

Tags: oracle, sql-tuning

I ran the Tuning Advisor on a query in Oracle SQL Developer. Under the SQL Profile tab there were two suggestions and I wanted to accept the first.

```
    execute dbms_sqltune.accept_sql_profile(task_name => 'staName',
        task_owner => 'DATA', replace => TRUE);
```

How do I accept the change or see what it is suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the SQL in SQL Developer and execute it.

To check the profiles use:

```
select * from dba_sql_profiles;
```

Particularly, look at the `SQL_TEXT` column

Comment: but how do I understand what did it do actually? I can't understand what was it indexes or something else. `SQL_TEXT` is just my SQL that I was testing

Comment: and why the heck it keeps offering me Findings after I've accepted the previous one?